# Displaying Meteor.user().username using Tracker React

Tags: meteor, meteor-react, meteor-tracker

I have been trying to display the Username of a Logged in user using Tracker React.
I have removed the auto-publish package.

/Client/components/dashboard/sidebar.jsx

```
import  React, {Component} from 'react'
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';

export default class Sidebar extends TrackerReact(Component) {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        subscription: {
            users: Meteor.subscribe('users')
        }
    };

}
 render() {
    return( 
     <div>
          <h1>{Meteor.user().username}</h1>
    </div>
);
}
```

/Server/publications/userPublications

```
Meteor.publish("users", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

I am getting a null object while `console.log(Meteor.user())`. However, I can see the current username using the Meteor DevTools for chrome.

What block of puzzle am I missing?

Comment: Don't you have to import Meteor?  Like `import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'`?

Comment: I fixed this problem with this [Link To Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417385/meteorjs-get-user-profile-on-client-side/43422269#43422269)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can use Meteor.user(). username

Try this instead

```
<h1>{{currentUser}}</h1>
```

Comment: I am getting `Sidebar.jsx:29Uncaught ReferenceError: currentUser is not defined`

Comment: I have a similar [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417385/meteorjs-get-user-profile-on-client-side/43422269#43422269)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [createContainer](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data) in order to manage it.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export class Sidebar extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    loggedIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    loggingIn: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    currentUser: PropTypes.shape({
      username: PropTypes.string
    })
  }
  render() {
    const { loggingIn, loggedIn } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {(() => {
          if (loggingIn) {
            return <Loading />
          } else if (loggedIn) {
            // whatever you want here.
          } else {
            <h1>Please Log In</h1>
          }
        })()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => ({
  user: Meteor.user(),
  loggedIn: !Meteor.userId(),
  loggingIn: Meteor.loggingIn()
}), Sidebar);
```

A few details here:

- `Meteor.loggingIn()` is a reactive variable that is run while the user is logging in. When this is happening, *there will not be a user object*.
- You should create a reactive container

Comment: Great reply!

Just a little question. Why did you add the extra **!** on the loggedIn assigment?

I think that it isn't needed. ;)

Comment: I have a similar [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417385/meteorjs-get-user-profile-on-client-side/43422269#43422269)