# MeteorJS: Get user profile on client side

Tags: reactjs, meteor

So, this problem has been well documented, yet here I am, stuck again...

On server side, I have publish:

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function(){ if (!this.userId) { return null; } 
return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'profile': 1}}); });
```

On client side router subscriptions, I have:

```
this.register('userData', Meteor.subscribe('userData'));
```

And then in my client code, I have:

```
if (Meteor.userId()) {
  var profile = Meteor.users.find(Meteor.userId()).profile;
  console.log(profile); // I keep getting undefined...
```

I am not using the autopublish or insecure package.

My data in the mongodb collection looks like:

```
{"_id" : "...", profile: { "password" : { "network" : "...", "picture" : "none" } }
```

My error says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
```

Thoughts?

Comment: When do you execute your client code?

Comment: @ghybs When the app starts

Comment: Are you waiting for your `'userData'` subscription to be ready?

Comment: @ghybs I don't think so.

Comment: I can bet you are checking that Meteor.userId() when you are not logged in. Only in this case you may get undefined or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turns out, most of my code was correct, but as ghybs pointed out above, I still needed to wait for the user data. So, here is my working code:

```
// in publish.js on the server
Meteor.publish('userData', function(){ if (!this.userId) { return null; } 
return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {'profile': 1}}); });

// in routes.jsx using FlowRouter
// after importing all the module external data
FlowRouter.route('/',{subscriptions:function(){
  this.register('getUser', Meteor.subscribe('userData'));
}, action() {
  mount(...etc...

// Keep in mind that I am using TrackerReact NPM to handle re-renders...
// in my component
if (FlowRouter.subsReady("getUser")) {
  // this returns an array with one object
  var userObject = Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The user profile is automatically published to the client, you don't need to write a custom publication to send it. That's why you should never store sensitive user information in the profile. You can get rid of that publication.

To access the profile in a component, all you need to do is wrap your component (or entire app) in a data container that sends the profile to the component. The reason you do this is that the container is reactive, so the component will load until the meteor user object is ready, then you can immediately access stuff stored in the profile.

Create container:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Navigation } from '/imports/ui/components/user-navigation/Navigation';

export default createContainer(() => {
    const loading = !Meteor.user();
    const user = Meteor.user();
    return { loading, user };
}, Navigation);
```

Access profile in component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Navigation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { user, loading } = this.props;
        return (

            loading ? <Loading /> :

            <div className="navigation">
                User's name is: { user.profile.firstname }
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. In my particular instance, this may not be applicable because I am already using TrackerReact instead of react-meteor-data for reactivity. Also, as I am using FlowRouter, I can subscribe through my routes and then wait for the subscription using `FlowRouter.subsReady()`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
var profile = Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).profile;
```

with

```
var profile = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()}).profile;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the query

```
var profile = Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).profile;
```

or this should work too

```
var profile = Meteor.user().profile;
```

Comment: Nah, still getting 'undefined'